# How does wasm-bindgen determine which bindings to generate?

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

When I run `wasm-bindgen --out-dir out some_binary.wasm` wasm-bindgen is able to figure out which functions have been annotated with `#[wasm_bindgen]` and to generate appropriate bindings for them so that they can be called from Javascript. How does this work? Is a special section of the WASM binary being used to hold this auxiliary information?

Comment: I've made some progress on answering this question. There is a comment at the top of [descriptors.rs from the wasm-bindgen-cli-support](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/blob/main/crates/cli-support/src/descriptors.rs) that states that the module looks for descriptor functions and executes them to get the necessary type information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is in the [Communicating types to wasm-bindgen section of the wasm-bindgen guide](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/contributing/design/describe.html).

In a nutshell, the `#[wasm_bindgen]` macro generates executable functions that describe the necessary bindings in Javascript inside `some_binary.wasm`. These functions are then executed by the wasm-bindgen CLI program to generate the Javascript bindings and a stripped WebAssembly module, i.e., `some_binary_bg.wasm`.